# 3rd party add ons

Tags: tools

Management is working on 2013 budget asked me to provide a list of software or 3rd party add on for sharepoint 2010.

I know I have a list of items (PDF rendition tool, sp admin tool, field level security add on, Active Directory web part for HR to disable account upon termination).

Wondering if someone would suggest a hand full of must have for SharePoint (from Admin Tools to front end).

Answer (score 2):

It really depends upon your requirement. AvePoint, ControlPoint, DeliverPoint, Quest, and Axceler are some really good ones.  All of the companies have good offerings. You'll just need to compare functionality and prices, and of course which tool is addressing your needs most.

Comment: as for admin tool I think ControlPoint is good. AvePoint needs dedicated server (unless you want to jepardize your current farm). Can someone talk about cook plug ins.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you first make an assessment of your business requirements (business solutions, administration, development, deployment,'user adoption', etc.) and then survey the various tools, utilities and applications that will help meet the requirements' needs. There are several websites that provide information which are categorized by the features and functionalities of the tools & applications - one such site is [SharePoint Reviews](http://www.sharepointreviews.com/) that'll help in your search.

Answer (score 2):

You will find the best rated SharePoint add-ons at Microsoft Pinpoint here:
http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/applications/search?q=sharepoint

Hope that helps.

Thanks, Frank